# How to parse multiple child pages, merge/append and pass upwards to parent level?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my first scrapy project - and admittedly, one of my first exercises with python as well. I am looking for a way to scrape multiple child pages, merge/append the content to a single value, and pass the data BACK / UP to the originating parent page. The number of child pages per parent page is variable as well - it could be as few as 1 but would never be 0 (possibly helpful for error handling?). Additionally, child pages could repeat and re-appear since they are NOT exclusive to a single parent. I have managed to pass parent page meta data DOWN to corresponding child pages but stumped on accomplishing the inverse.

Here is an example page structure:

```
Top Level Domain
     - Pagination/Index Page #1 (parse recipe links)
          - Recipe #1 (select info & parse ingredient links)
               - Ingredient #1 (select info)
               - Ingredient #2 (select info)
               - Ingredient #3 (select info)
          - Recipe #2
               - Ingredient #1
          - Recipe #3
               - Ingredient #1
               - Ingredient #2
     - Pagination/Index Page #2
          - Recipe #N
               - Ingredient #N
               - ...
     - Pagination/Index Page #3
     - ... continued
```

The output I am looking for (per recipe) is something like the below:

```
{
"recipe_title": "Gin & Tonic",
"recipe_posted_date": "May 2, 2019",
"recipe_url": "www.XYZ.com/gandt.html",
"recipe_instructions": "<block of text here>",
"recipe_ingredients": ["gin", "tonic water", "lime wedge"],
"recipe_calorie_total": "135 calories",
"recipe_calorie_list": ["60 calories", "70 calories", "5 calories"]
}
```

I am extracting the URL for each ingredient from the respective recipe page. I need to extract the calorie count from each ingredient page, merge it with the calorie count of the other ingredients, and ideally yield a single item. Since a single ingredient is not exclusive to a single recipe, I need to be able to re-visit an ingredient page later in my crawl.

(note - this is not the real example since calorie count obviously varies based on volume required by recipe)

My posted code is getting me close to what I'm looking for but I have to imagine there is a more graceful way to solve the problem. The posted code is successful at passing DOWN the recipe's meta data to the ingredient level, looping through the ingredients, and appending the calorie count. Since the info is being passed down though, I am yielding at the ingredient level and creating a number of recipe duplicates (one per ingredient) until I loop through the last ingredient. At this stage, I'm looking to add in the ingredient index number so that I can somehow retain the record with the greatest Ingredient Index# per Recipe URL. Before I got to that point, I figured I would turn to the pro's here for guidance.

Scraper code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from recipe_scraper.items import RecipeItem

class RecipeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Recipe'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/recipes/']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=()
                ,restrict_css=('.pagination')
                ,unique=True
            )
            ,callback='parse_index_page'
            ,follow=True
        ),
    )

def parse_index_page(self, response):
    print('Processing Index Page.. ' + response.url)
    index_url = response.url
    recipe_urls = response.css('.recipe > a::attr(href)').getall()
    for a in recipe_urls:
        request = scrapy.Request(a, callback=self.parse_recipe_page)
        request.meta['index_url'] = index_url
        yield request

def parse_recipe_page(self, response):
    print('Processing Recipe Page.. ' + response.url)
    Recipe_url = response.url
    Recipe_title = response.css('.Recipe_title::text').extract()[0]
    Recipe_posted_date = response.css('.Recipe_posted_date::text').extract()[0]
    Recipe_instructions = response.css('.Recipe_instructions::text').extract()[0]
    Recipe_ingredients = response.xpath('//ul[@class="ingredients"]//li[@class="ingredient"]/a/text()').getall()
    Recipe_ingredient_urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="ingredients"]//li[@class="ingredient"]/a/@href').getall()
    Recipe_calorie_list_append = []
    Recipe_calorie_list = []
    Recipe_calorie_total = []
    Recipe_item = RecipeItem()
    Recipe_item['index_url'] = response.meta["index_url"]
    Recipe_item['Recipe_url'] = Recipe_url
    Recipe_item['Recipe_title'] = Recipe_title
    Recipe_item['Recipe_posted_date'] = Recipe_posted_date
    Recipe_item['Recipe_instructions'] = Recipe_instructions
    Recipe_item['Recipe_ingredients'] = Recipe_ingredients
    Recipe_item['Recipe_ingredient_urls'] = Recipe_ingredient_urls
    Recipe_item['Recipe_ingredient_url_count'] = len(Recipe_ingredient_urls)
    Recipe_calorie_list.clear()
    Recipe_ingredient_url_index = 0
    while Recipe_ingredient_url_index < len(Recipe_ingredient_urls):
        ingredient_request = scrapy.Request(Recipe_ingredient_urls[Recipe_ingredient_url_index], callback=self.parse_ingredient_page, dont_filter=True)
        ingredient_request.meta['Recipe_item'] = Recipe_item
        ingredient_request.meta['Recipe_calorie_list'] = Recipe_calorie_list
        yield ingredient_request
        Recipe_calorie_list_append.append(Recipe_calorie_list)
        Recipe_ingredient_url_index += 1

def parse_ingredient_page(self, response):
    print('Processing Ingredient Page.. ' + response.url)
    Recipe_item = response.meta['Recipe_item']
    Recipe_calorie_list = response.meta["Recipe_calorie_list"]
    ingredient_url = response.url
    ingredient_calorie_total = response.css('div.calorie::text').getall()
    Recipe_calorie_list.append(ingredient_calorie_total)
    Recipe_item['Recipe_calorie_list'] = Recipe_calorie_list
    yield Recipe_item
    Recipe_calorie_list.clear()
```

As is, my less than ideal output is as follows (note the calorie list):

```
{
"recipe_title": "Gin & Tonic",
"recipe_posted_date": "May 2, 2019",
"recipe_url": "www.XYZ.com/gandt.html",
"recipe_instructions": "<block of text here>",
"recipe_ingredients": ["gin", "tonic water", "lime wedge"],
"recipe_calorie_total": [],
"recipe_calorie_list": ["60 calories"]
},
{
"recipe_title": "Gin & Tonic",
"recipe_posted_date": "May 2, 2019",
"recipe_url": "www.XYZ.com/gandt.html",
"recipe_instructions": "<block of text here>",
"recipe_ingredients": ["gin", "tonic water", "lime wedge"],
"recipe_calorie_total": [],
"recipe_calorie_list": ["60 calories", "70 calories"]
},
{
"recipe_title": "Gin & Tonic",
"recipe_posted_date": "May 2, 2019",
"recipe_url": "www.XYZ.com/gandt.html",
"recipe_instructions": "<block of text here>",
"recipe_ingredients": ["gin", "tonic water", "lime wedge"],
"recipe_calorie_total": [],
"recipe_calorie_list": ["60 calories", "70 calories", "5 calories"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to scrape recipes and ingredients separately, as different items, and then do some post-processing after the crawling has finished, using regular Python for example, that merges recipe and ingredient data as needed. This is the most efficient solution.

Alternatively, you could extract ingredient URLs from recipe responses and, instead of yielding requests for all of them at once, you can yield a request for the first ingredient and save the remaining ingredient URLs to the new request `meta`, along with the recipe item. When an ingredient response is received, you parse all needed information into `meta` and yield a new request for the next ingredient URL. When there are no more ingredient URLs, you yield your complete recipe item.

For example:

```
def _handle_next_ingredient(self, recipe, ingredient_urls):
    try:
        return Request(
            ingredient_urls.pop(),
            callback=self.parse_ingredient,
            meta={'recipe': recipe, 'ingredient_urls': ingredient_urls},
        )
    except IndexError:
        return recipe

def parse_recipe(self, response):
    recipe = {}, ingredient_urls = []
    # [Extract needed data into recipe and ingredient URLs into ingredient_urls]
    yield self._handle_next_ingredient(recipe, ingredient_urls)

def parse_ingredient(self, response):
    recipe = response.meta['recipe']
    # [Extend recipe with the information of this ingredient]
    yield self._handle_next_ingredient(recipe, response.meta['ingredient_urls'])
```

Note, however, that if two or more recipes can have the same ingredient URL, you will have to add `dont_filter=True` to your requests, repeating multiple requests for the same ingredients. Seriously consider the first suggestion instead, if ingredient URLs are not recipe-specific.

Comment: Many thanks @Gallaecio - I have considered your first suggestion of independent scrapes but not sure where to begin with post-processing.

Comment: You could (1) export all items (both recipes and ingredients) to a JSON Lines file, and then run a post-processing script that (2) splits that file in two different files, one with recipes and another with ingredients, and then (3) read the recipes file line by line, and for each recipe read ingredient data from the ingredient file for each ingredient URL from the recipe, and write the final recipe data into a final, JSON Lines file. This is general Python, so get started and, if you get really stuck, ask another question about your new problem.

Comment: Thanks again! I had additional comments in my reply but didn't realize there was a 5-minute window for edits. All good, you answered my questions anyway. Will give that a shot - thank you!